# Trying to add bulk data to database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to add a large amount of data to a table in a database with thousands of entries, problem is I am used to the format being inside a ('sampleentry, sampleentry , sampleentry , ') type of entry. The data is continuous, and does not have a ':' at the end of each line of entry. If someone could assist me on how to import this into a table in SQL Server using the following data provided, it would be very helpful.

```
USE master
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'GlobalAirportDatabase')
    DROP DATABASE GlobalAirportDatabase

CREATE DATABASE GlobalAirportDatabase
GO

USE GlobalAirportDatabase

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTABLEname' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')
    DROP TABLE dbo.tblAirport;
GO

CREATE TABLE tblAirport
(
    AirportID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ICAOCode VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    AirportCode VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    strName VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    strCity VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    strCountry VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    degLat DEC(7,2) NULL,
    minLat DEC(7,2) NULL,
    secLat DEC(7,2) NULL,
    Equator VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    degLong DEC(7,2) NULL,
    minLong DEC(7,2) NULL,
    secLong DEC(7,2) NULL,
    Meridian VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    strElevation VARCHAR(4) NULL,
)
GO

ALTER TABLE tblAirport 
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (AirportID)
GO

INSERT INTO tblAirport (ICAOCode, AirportCode, strName, strCity, strCountry, degLat, minLat, secLat, Equator, degLong, minLong, secLong, Meridian, strElevation,)
VALUES
AYGA:GKA:GOROKA:GOROKA:PAPUA NEW GUINEA:06:04:54:S:145:23:30:E:5282
AYLA:LAE::LAE:PAPUA NEW GUINEA:00:00:00:U:00:00:00:U:0000
AYMD:MAG:MADANG:MADANG:PAPUA NEW GUINEA:05:12:25:S:145:47:19:E:0020
AYMH:HGU:MOUNT HAGEN:MOUNT HAGEN:PAPUA NEW GUINEA:05:49:34:S:144:17:46:E:5388
AYNZ:LAE:NADZAB:NADZAB:PAPUA NEW GUINEA:06:34:11:S:146:43:34:E:0239
AYPY:POM:PORT MORESBY JACKSONS INTERNATIONAL:PORT MORESBY:PAPUA NEW GUINEA:09:26:36:S:147:13:12:E:0146
AYRB:RAB::RABAUL:PAPUA NEW GUINEA:00:00:00:U:00:00:00:U:0000
AYWK:WWK:WEWAK INTERNATIONAL:WEWAK:PAPUA NEW GUINEA:03:35:01:S:143:40:09:E:0019
BGAM:N/A::ANGMAGSSALIK:GREENLAND:00:00:00:U:00:00:00:U:0000
BGAS:N/A::ANGISSOQ:GREENLAND:00:00:00:U:00:00:00:U:0000
BGAT:N/A::APUTITEQ:GREENLAND:00:00:00:U:00:00:00:U:0000
BGBW:UAK:NARSARSUAQ:NARSSARSSUAQ:GREENLAND:61:09:40:N:45:25:39:U:0112
BGCH:JCH::CHRISTIANSHAAB:GREENLAND:00:00:00:U:00:00:00:U:0000
```

Comment: which programming language are you using in back-end? or do you have to do this directly to the database?

Comment: Have you ever heard about [CTE's](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

Comment: No I have not heard about CTE's, are they worth investigating for this task? and I'm not sure what you mean by that question, I'm not a very experienced programmer. I am using C#, and the data is posted directly on a c# query.

Comment: But this data come from a text file? or another external file? I'm just asking because my solution will depend on the answer to my question. I mean the data you are about to insert on DB

Comment: From a text file

Comment: Another question: this txt file have the registries exaclty like the ones you posted on your question? I mean when you open the .txt file you find an unique big line with all the info or are they organized 1 registry per line?

Comment: Yes, CTE's might be helpful, because they can split your data on delimiter (`:`)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Julio, they seemed to be one big line, but when I pasted them to SQL, it organised them in one registry per line

Comment: I'd use c# to shred the records into what you need, then use the SQLBulkCopy class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx ) to blast the data in.

Comment: You can use regex in C# I think is the best way, Look at this info (https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No problem bro. I'm glad you made it. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You could use a code editor like ["sublime text"](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) then copy the information you have on the .txt file and paste it to sublime text then

2)Then press "ctrl + H". It will appear the "replace by" function down at the bottom of the editor window.

3) Replace the ":" character for "," character using a regular expresion that excludes replacing the ":" between numbers by "," and excludes to replace the blank spaces " " by ",". You should put the ";" in the "Find What:" input and 
the regular expresion on the "Replace with" input. Then you click "Replace all" button.

4) Use another regular expresion that validates the "blank spaces". The regular expresion will depend on if the registries are separated by a "simple blank space" or by an "entire line". With this you can finish in formatting the information of the .txt file in ("sample", "sample", "sample") as you want to

I am starting to use C# so I don't know if C# can use regex (regular expresions) and how to implement it but if you know who to use regular expresion on C# it will be much easier to do it that way because your code will do the process 
automatically.